# What's the proper way to create Group Chat feature using Ejabberd and Smack for Android?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I'm using smack in my Android project. I'm trying to create a Telegram, WhatsApp like group feature. The problem is, a user can't get messages from a conference room when the user is offline. I've to rejoin the room and get history to get new messages? Is there any way, which can deliver the messages without rejoining the room.

Also trying Ejabberd **mod_multicast**(XEP-0033). I'm getting **Packet relay is denied by service policy** error.

Need help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can take look at MUC-SUB feature of ejabberd. It is designed for the same reason. [Here](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/xmpp-clients-bots/proposed-extensions/muc-sub/) is more detail you can refer.

Comment: Thanks for answering @Darshan :) ...Can you tell me how to send IQ stanza to server using Smack android library?